# solr performance with large data retrieval

Tags: hadoop, search, solr, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

My use case

- I am having 20gb file per day. (pipe delimited text file)
- I have indexed 90 days data (20 * 90 gb)
- Record count - 5.5 billion
- total  fields - 30
- Indexed fields - called_number, calling_number, time_key
- All other fields are stored as per schema.cml
- index size - 300gb
- No of shards = 4

I used below method to index (org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool)

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-*-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.M apReduceIndexerTool \
    --morphline-file $path/morphlines.conf –output -dir hdfs://MASTERNODE:8020/$path2 \
    --go-live --zk-host MASTERNODE:2181/solr \
    --collection COLLECTIONNAME \
    --mappers 4 \
    --reducers 12 hdfs://Masternode/path/asd.txt
```

In my test bed I have 4 data nodes and 1 name node. (Test bed on cloudera 5.4.7)
each node has 256gb ram,Any performance increasing tips i should follow in solr?

It took around 120 sec to get  3000 record out put in one search (range query based on time key). But after first time query, its getting cached and then if I executed again I'm getting response less than 1 sec with larger records out put as well (10000 record out put also getting with in 1 sec)

Note that when retrieving 10 - 20 records, then performance was good on first time itself.